# (Modal) Dialog Window not captured when taking screenshot

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, modal-dialog

I have a C# project with WPF and CAB where I want to take a screenshot of the entire screen including a modal dialog that pops up. When I take a screenshot with either CopyFromScreen or some interop features like the one described [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/02/08/capturing-screen-images-in-wpf-using-gdi-win32-and-a-little-wpf-interop-help) the modal dialog window only appears on the screenshot when the Visual Style is set to full Aero Glass.

I cannot guarantee that Aero Glass is enabled. I apart from the Glass restriction I cannot pinpoint what leads to this problem and I am unable to create a sandbox solution to duplicate the problem. Even using the tool in the previous link to create the screenshot from an external application fails. The only way to take this screenshot with glass disabled seems to be the Print Key (the OS-based screenshot).

Any idea on what I can try to take a proper screenshot without enabling Aero Glass?

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't that the standard behaviour? You can only capture popups, tooltips and other top level graphics when using the keyboard `PrintScrn` button. All other methods take focus away from these controls and so they disappear.

Comment: If that is the case, why would it work with Aero Glass enabled?

Comment: I don't know enough about Aero Glass to comment on that. However, the situation that you describe is the same situation that I've had ever since starting to program. As I said, I could be wrong, but in my opinion, that is the normal behaviour.